# Ошибка в передаче аргумента в функцию

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели

Есть ошибка, `cmap` передается в такую фукнцию

```
void fill_cmap( char **cmap, const char *file );
```

Вот код функции

```
void Loader::load(const char *file )
{
    char cmap[lines][width];
    fill_cmap ( &cmap[0], file );
    std::printf ( "%s\n", cmap[0] );
}
```

Выводится вот такая ошибка

```
                ^
/home/xverizex/codelite_projects/expreience/Loader.cpp: In member function 'void Loader::load(const char*)':
```

Вот код fill_cmap.

```
void Loader::fill_cmap ( char **cmap, const char *file )
{
    FILE *fd = fopen ( file, "r" );
    register int line = lines;
    char cline[1024];
    for ( ; line >= 0; line-- ) {
        fgets ( &cline[0], 1023, fd );
        char *end = strchr ( &cline[0], '\n' );
        *end = 0;
        copy_line ( &cmap[line][0], &cline[0] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну и? Функция хочет `char **`. Вы передаете не  `char **`. Получается ошибка.

Comment: А как передать char **

Comment: Думаю, вам нужно передавать **не** `char**` - как вы с ним работаете? Похоже на XY-проблему (вопрос "какой рукой держать микроскоп" вместо "как забить гвоздь"). Покажите-ка код `fill_cmap`... И, кстати, вы привели сообщение, **где** ошибка, но не **какая** - текст сообщения об ошибке вы проингнорировали (к счастью, тут она очевидна).

Comment: отредактировал начальный вопрос и включил туда функцию fill_cmap.

Comment: Бессмысленное занятие пытаться передавать так, как вы хотите. Как бы вы ни передавали как `char**` двумерный массив, он не преобразуется обратно в двумерный массив для вызова `copy_line ( &cmap[line][0]`. Либо нужно работать с конкретным типом `char[][M]` с точно известным во время компиляции `M`, либо создавать `cmap` именно как массив указателей, каждый из которых указывает на массив `char`'ов, либо вообще как-то переписывать функции по-другому. Да, и забудьте о ключевом слове `register` - это не ошибка, но оно давно ничего не дает...

Comment: тогда я перенесу код из fill_map в load

Comment: И не забудьте закрыть файл - раз вы работаете не с `ifstream`, сам он не закроется. Утечка, однако :)